# Problem with old code for a Calabi-Yau manifold

Tags: graphics3d, visualization

I would like to draw a Calabi-Yau space in *Mathematica*. From Andrew J. Hanson's [paper](http://www.cs.indiana.edu/~hansona/papers/CP2-94.pdf) (page 6) about this topic, I got the following code, which just does not show anything at all in my *Mathematica* test version.
I am a newbie coming from the processing/open frameworks direction. Any help would be highly appreciated - Thank you!

```
cCos[theta_, xi_] := .5 (Eˆ (xi + I theta) + Eˆ (-xi - I theta));

cSin[theta_, xi_] := (-.5 I) (Eˆ (xi + I theta) - Eˆ (-xi - I theta));

z1[theta_, xi_, n_, k_] := Eˆ (k*2*Pi*I/n)*cCos[theta, xi] ˆ (2.0/n);

z2[theta_, xi_, n_, k_] := Eˆ (k*2*Pi*I/n)*cSin[theta, xi] ˆ (2.0/n);

pz1[theta_, xi_, n_, k_] := Eˆ ((xi + I theta)/n)*Eˆ (k*2*Pi*I/n);

pz2[theta_, xi_, n_, k_] := Eˆ ((-xi - I theta)/n)*Eˆ (-k*2*Pi*I/n);

MakePolygons[vl_List] := 
 Block[{l = vl, l1 = Map[RotateLeft, vl], mesh}, 
  mesh = {l, l1, RotateLeft[l1], RotateLeft[l]};
  mesh = Map[Drop[#, -1] &, mesh, {1}];
  mesh = Map[Drop[#, -1] &, mesh, {2}];
  Polygon /@ Transpose[Map[Flatten[#, 1] &, mesh]]]

n1 = 3; n2 = 3; xiSteps = 17; xiMax = 1; thetaSteps = 17; angle = Pi/4;

cosA = Cos[angle]; sinA = Sin[angle];

Do[Do[patch33[k1 + 1, k2 + 1] = 
    MakePolygons[
     Table[Block[{z1Val = N[z1[theta, xi, n1, k1]], 
        z2Val = N[z2[theta, xi, n2, k2]]}, {Re[z1Val], Re[z2Val], 
        cosA*Im[z1Val] + sinA*Im[z2Val]}], {xi, -xiMax, 
       xiMax, (2*xiMax)/(xiSteps - 1)}, {theta, 0, 
       Pi/2, (Pi/2)/(thetaSteps - 1)}]], {k1, 0, n1 - 1}], {k2, 0, 
   n2 - 1}];
zi -> pzi and Pi/2 -> 2 Pi;

bs0 = 0.8; bs1 = 0.2; lt = 0.9;

surface33 = 
  Show[Graphics3D[
    Table[[Block[{bs = 
          If[And[k1 == 0, k2 == 0], bs0, bs1]}, {RGBColor[
          bs + lt*k1/(n1 - 1), bs + lt*k2/(n2 - 1), bs], 
         patch33[k1 + 1, k2 + 1]}] {k1, 0, n1 - 1}, {k2, 0, n2 - 1}], 
     Lighting -> False, Axes -> None, Boxed -> False, 
     BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 1}, ViewPoint -> {2.9, 1.0, 1.4}]]];
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There are many mistakes which I believe come from the Copy/Paste:

```
cCos[theta_, xi_] := .5 (E^(xi + I theta) + E^ (-xi - I theta));
cSin[theta_, xi_] := (-.5 I) (E^ (xi + I theta) - E^ (-xi - I theta));
z1[theta_, xi_, n_, k_] := E^ (k*2*Pi*I/n)*cCos[theta, xi] ^ (2.0/n);
z2[theta_, xi_, n_, k_] := E^ (k*2*Pi*I/n)*cSin[theta, xi] ^ (2.0/n);
pz1[theta_, xi_, n_, k_] := E^ ((xi + I theta)/n)*E^ (k*2*Pi*I/n);
pz2[theta_, xi_, n_, k_] := E^ ((-xi - I theta)/n)*E^ (-k*2*Pi*I/n);
MakePolygons[vl_List] := 
 Block[{l = vl, l1 = Map[RotateLeft, vl], mesh}, 
  mesh = {l, l1, RotateLeft[l1], RotateLeft[l]};
  mesh = Map[Drop[#, -1] &, mesh, {1}];
  mesh = Map[Drop[#, -1] &, mesh, {2}];
  Polygon /@ Transpose[Map[Flatten[#, 1] &, mesh]]]

n1 = 3; n2 = 3; xiSteps = 17; xiMax = 1; thetaSteps = 17; angle = Pi/4;

cosA = Cos[angle]; sinA = Sin[angle];

Do[Do[patch33[k1 + 1, k2 + 1] = 
    MakePolygons[
     Table[Block[{z1Val = N[z1[theta, xi, n1, k1]], 
        z2Val = N[z2[theta, xi, n2, k2]]}, {Re[z1Val], Re[z2Val], 
        cosA*Im[z1Val] + sinA*Im[z2Val]}], {xi, -xiMax, 
       xiMax, (2*xiMax)/(xiSteps - 1)}, {theta, 0, 
       Pi/2, (Pi/2)/(thetaSteps - 1)}]], {k1, 0, n1 - 1}], {k2, 0, n2 - 1}];

bs0 = 0.8; bs1 = 0.2; lt = 0.9;

surface33 = 
 Show[Graphics3D[
   Table[Block[{bs = If[And[k1 == 0, k2 == 0], bs0, bs1]}, {RGBColor[
       bs + lt*k1/(n1 - 1), bs + lt*k2/(n2 - 1), bs], 
      patch33[k1 + 1, k2 + 1]}], {k1, 0, n1 - 1}, {k2, 0, n2 - 1}], 
   Lighting -> Automatic, Axes -> None, Boxed -> False, 
   BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 1}, ViewPoint -> {2.9, 1.0, 1.4}]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Dear Öska - awesome! thank you very much for fixing it so fast. THX!!!!

Answer (score 11):

Considering the use of the old utility `MakePolygons[]` by Roman Maeder, as well as the year Hanson's paper appeared, I believe this was done during the time one still had to load a package to be able to use `ParametricPlot3D[]`. Since `ParametricPlot3D[]` has been built-in for quite a while now, please allow me to present a modernized plot of the Fermat surface for $x^3 + y^3 = 1$:

```
z1[θ_, ξ_, n_, k_] := Exp[2 π I k/n] Cosh[ξ + I θ]^(2/n);
z2[θ_, ξ_, n_, k_] := Exp[2 π I k/n] Sinh[ξ + I θ]^(2/n);

With[{n1 = 3, n2 = 3, φ = π/4, bs0 = 0.8, bs1 = 0.2, lt = 0.9}, 
     ParametricPlot3D[Flatten[Table[
                      With[{z1Val = z1[θ, ξ, n1, k1], z2Val = z2[θ, ξ, n2, k2]},
                           {Re[z1Val], Re[z2Val],
                            Cos[φ] Im[z1Val] + Sin[φ] Im[z2Val]}],
                                    {k1, 0, n1 - 1}, {k2, 0, n2 - 1}], 1],
                      {ξ, -1, 1}, {θ, 0, π/2}, Axes -> None, Boxed -> False,
                      Evaluated -> True, Lighting -> "Neutral", 
                      PlotStyle -> Flatten[Table[
                      With[{b = bs1 + (bs0 - bs1) Boole[k1 == k2 == 0]}, 
                           RGBColor[b + lt k1/(n1 - 1), b + lt k2/(n2 - 1), b]],
                          {k1, 0, n1 - 1}, {k2, 0, n2 - 1}]],
                      ViewPoint -> {2.9, 1.0, 1.4}]]
```

[image: Calabi-Yau manifold for x^3 + y^3 = 1]

Here's a plot of a different Calabi-Yau manifold; I'll let you guess what parameters I used to generate this:
[image: guess this picture]

Comment: M.,
is there a copyright in your image?
https://i.stack.imgur.com/3csGv.png
Can we use it?
Thank you

Comment: @francis, you are free to use it; all that's needed is for you to link to this post for credit.

Comment: @JM., thank you for your reply