# How to plot such beautiful Calabi–Yau manifold?

Tags: plotting

I only found some limited [answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/61590/problem-with-old-code-for-a-calabi-yau-manifold) close to the picture.

[image]

[video](https://tbm-auth.alicdn.com/73bbe9f95b148212/70ffa26f23db4475/20230723_3af856fe88aa2fa9_419694236345_41659817930268_published_mp4_264_hd_taobao.mp4?auth_key=1710662628-0-0-573609d464e80f0fff15451180665566&biz=tbs_vsucai-0dce6349e3769369&t=2131176f17106599280032483e1465&t=2131176f17106599280032483e1465&b=tbs_vsucai&p=cloudvideo_http_tb_seller_vsucai_publish)
[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- rewrite the code from @J.M.'seventualburnout https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/89095/72111
- We set `n1=7,n2=7`  and `PlotStyle -> None, MeshStyle -> White,  ViewPoint -> {2.5, 2.2, 1.4}, Background -> Darker@Blue`

```
z1[θ_, ξ_, n_, k_] := 
  Exp[2  π  I  k/n]  Cosh[ξ + I  θ]^(2/n);
z2[θ_, ξ_, n_, k_] := 
 Exp[2  π  I  k/n]  Sinh[ξ + I  θ]^(2/n); With[{n1 = 7,
   n2 = 7, φ = π/4, bs0 = 0.8, bs1 = 0.2, lt = 0.9}, 
 ParametricPlot3D[
  Flatten[Table[
    With[{z1Val = z1[θ, ξ, n1, k1], 
      z2Val = z2[θ, ξ, n2, k2]}, {Re[z1Val], Re[z2Val], 
      Cos[φ]  Im[z1Val] + 
       Sin[φ]  Im[z2Val]}], {k1, 0, n1 - 1}, {k2, 0, 
     n2 - 1}], 1], {ξ, -1, 1}, {θ, 0, π/2}, 
  Axes -> None, Boxed -> False, Evaluated -> True, 
  Lighting -> "Neutral", PlotStyle -> None, MeshStyle -> White, 
  ViewPoint -> {2.5, 2.2, 1.4}, Background -> Darker@Blue]]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you. It looks really cool. Is is possible to make it rotate along some given axis? I tried to define it as a 3D object and use manipulate and rotate, but it did not work correctly.@cvgmt

Comment: @metroidman `Tour3DVideo`