# How to make a ParametricPlot3D curve rotate smoothly?

Tags: plotting, graphics3d, rotation

I'm trying to make the complicated ParametricPlot3D [curve](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/300632/how-to-plot-such-beautiful-calabi-yau-manifold) rotate along the z-axis smoothly.
I tried Rotate on a simple 3D object first.

```
Manipulate[Graphics3D[Rotate[Cuboid[], y, {0, 0, 1}], Boxed -> False], {y, 0, 180 Degree}]
```

It works fine. But it does not work on the ParametricPlot3D curve, because "Graphics3DBox is not a Graphics3D primitive or directive.".

Then I tried RotationMatrix on ParametricPlot3D curve and it works correctly on simple curves.

```
Manipulate[ParametricPlot3D[RotationMatrix[\[Theta], {x, y, z}] . {Cos[t], Sin[t], t/10}, {t, 0,10}, PlotRange -> All, AxesLabel -> {"X", "Y", "Z"}], {{\[Theta], 0}, 0, 2   \[Pi]}, {{x, 0}, -1, 1}, {{y, 0}, -1, 1}, {{z, 1}, -1, 1}]
```

But when the curve becomes complicated, it rotates slowly or ugly.

```
Manipulate[ParametricPlot3D[RotationMatrix[mm, {x, y, z}] . {Cos[t]  (3 + r  Cos[t/2]), Sin[t]  (3 + r  Cos[t/2]), r  Sin[t/2]}, {r, -1, 1}, {t, 0, 2  Pi}, Mesh -> {5, 10}, PlotStyle -> FaceForm[Red, Yellow], PlotRange -> {{-5, 5}, {-5, 5}, {-5, 5}}], {{mm, 0}, 0, 2   \[Pi], \[Pi]/20}, {{x, 0}, -1, 1}, {{y, 0}, -1, 1}, {{z, 1}, -1,1}]
```

Is it possible to make the rotation faster without deformation, like when we drag the object using the mouse?

Comment: Precompute all needed arrangements of your plot into a table and then use `Manipulate` to display particular item of the table.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The use of `Dynamic` below keeps the `ParametricPlot` from reevaluating, which leads to smooth behavior:

```
Manipulate[
 MapAt[
  Dynamic@Rotate[#, mm, {x, y, z}] &, 
  ParametricPlot3D[{Cos[t]   (3 + r   Cos[t/2]), 
    Sin[t]   (3 + r   Cos[t/2]), r   Sin[t/2]}, {r, -1, 1}, {t, 0, 
    2   Pi}, Mesh -> {5, 10}, PlotStyle -> FaceForm[Red, Yellow], 
   PlotRange -> {{-5, 5}, {-5, 5}, {-5, 5}}],
  1]
 , {{mm, 0}, 0, 2    \[Pi], \[Pi]/20}, {{x, 0}, -1, 1}, {{y, 0}, -1, 
  1}, {{z, 1}, -1, 1}]
```

Answer (score 6):

```
plot = ParametricPlot3D[{Cos[t] (3 + r Cos[t/2]), 
    Sin[t] (3 + r Cos[t/2]), r Sin[t/2]}, {r, -1, 1}, {t, 0, 2 Pi}, 
   Mesh -> {5, 10}, PlotStyle -> FaceForm[Red, Yellow], 
   PlotRange -> {{-5, 5}, {-5, 5}, {-5, 5}}];
table = Table[
   Graphics3D[
    GeometricTransformation[plot[[1]], 
     RotationTransform[fi, {0, 1, 0}]], plot[[2]]], {fi, 0, 
    2 Pi, Pi/21}];
Manipulate[table[[i]], {i, 1, Length[table], 1}]
```

---

[image]

Answer (score 5):

**Edit**

- Or only use `Evaluate` and `PerformanceGoal -> "Quality"`.

```
Manipulate[
 ParametricPlot3D[
  RotationMatrix[mm, {x, y, z}] . {Cos[t]    (3 + r    Cos[t/2]), 
     Sin[t]    (3 + r    Cos[t/2]), r    Sin[t/2]} // 
   Evaluate, {r, -1, 1}, {t, 0, 2    Pi}, Mesh -> {5, 10}, 
  PlotStyle -> FaceForm[Red, Yellow], 
  PlotRange -> {{-5, 5}, {-5, 5}, {-5, 5}}, 
  PerformanceGoal -> "Quality"], {{mm, 0}, 0, 
  2     π, π/20}, {{x, 0}, -1, 1}, {{y, 0}, -1, 
  1}, {{z, 1}, -1, 1}]
```

**Original**

- Use `First` to `ParametricPlot3D` to extract the graphics data and use `GeometricTransformation` to act on such object.
- Set `PerformanceGoal -> "Quality"` in `ParametricPlot3D`.

```
Manipulate[
 Graphics3D[
  GeometricTransformation[
   First@ParametricPlot3D[{Cos[t]   (3 + r   Cos[t/2]), 
      Sin[t]   (3 + r   Cos[t/2]), r   Sin[t/2]}, {r, -1, 1}, {t, 0, 
      2   Pi}, Mesh -> {5, 10}, PlotStyle -> FaceForm[Red, Yellow], 
     PlotRange -> {{-5, 5}, {-5, 5}, {-5, 5}}, 
     PerformanceGoal -> "Quality"], 
   RotationTransform[mm, {x, y, z}]]], {{mm, 0}, 0, 
  2    π, π/20}, {{x, 0}, -1, 1}, {{y, 0}, -1, 
  1}, {{z, 1}, -1, 1}]
```

Answer (score 5):

You just need to precompute your transformed curve! Otherwise, the transformation matrix and the dot product are recomputed every time you change the parameters, which is very computationally expensive.

```
curve[m_, x_, y_, z_] = 
 Refine[RotationMatrix[m, {x, y, z}], {x, y, z} ∈ 
     Reals] . {Cos[t] (3 + r Cos[t/2]), Sin[t] (3 + r Cos[t/2]), 
    r Sin[t/2]} // Simplify

Manipulate[
 ParametricPlot3D[
  Evaluate@curve[mm, x, y, z], {r, -1, 1}, {t, 0, 2 Pi}, 
  Mesh -> {5, 10}, PlotStyle -> FaceForm[Red, Yellow], 
  PlotRange -> {{-5, 5}, {-5, 5}, {-5, 5}}], {{mm, 0}, 0, 
  2 π, π/20}, {{x, 0}, -1, 1}, {{y, 0}, -1, 1}, {{z, 1}, -1, 1}]
```